# Time complexity of counting all nodes with a given key in a ternary tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, big-o, time-complexity

I need to find the time complexity of a function in my program. It searches for all the internal nodes of the ternary tree which have the given key. This tree is filled at random. I think I've managed to write the code but I have no idea how to calculate the complexity.

Here is the function and the structs of the tree:

```
typedef struct _no
{
    int chave; 
    struct _no *F[3]; 
} TipoNo;

typedef TipoNo *TipoArvore;

int noSubTree (TipoArvore t, int x){
    int n;
    if (t == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        if(t->F[0] == NULL && t->F[1] == NULL && t->F[2] == NULL ){
             return 0;
        }
        else if(t->chave == x) {                 
          return 1 + noSubTree(t->F[0], x) + 
                     noSubTree(t->F[1], x) + 
                     noSubTree(t->F[2], x);
        }
        else {
          return 0 + noSubTree(t->F[0], x) +
                     noSubTree(t->F[1], x) +
                     noSubTree(t->F[2], x);
       }
    }
 }
```

I'd be most grateful if anyone could explain to me how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is to think about

- How many times each node is visited, and
- How much work is done per node visit.

Notice that your code does O(1) work every time it visits a node - it just fires off more recursive calls and optionally adds one to the result. You also visit each node exactly once. Each node only calls the function on its children, so eventually all nodes will be reached, and since all calls are directed downwards and never overlap no node will be visited twice.

Therefore, the total time complexity is Θ(n), where n is the total number of nodes in the tree.

As a totally unrelated aside: since you're writing this code in C, you can condense some of your cases together. For example, look at these lines of code:

```
if(t->chave == x) {                 
    return 1 + noSubTree(t->F[0], x) + 
               noSubTree(t->F[1], x) + 
               noSubTree(t->F[2], x);
}
else {
   return 0 + noSubTree(t->F[0], x) +
              noSubTree(t->F[1], x) +
              noSubTree(t->F[2], x);
}
```

In C, the logical operator `==` evaluates to 1 if the two arguments are equal and 0 otherwise. Therefore, you can condense these cases together into just this:

```
return (t->chave == x) + noSubTree(t->F[0], x) +
                         noSubTree(t->F[1], x) +
                         noSubTree(t->F[2], x);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice analysis, but doesn't it affects readability by condensing that if statement?

Comment: @Sinn- I think that's a judgment call. I personally find it a bit easier to read, but depending on the group of programmers reading/maintaining it, it might not be a good call.

Answer (score 0):

`noSubTree()` - given the root as the starting point - hits every node of your tree, but it hits each one only once, so the complexity of this function is O(n).

If you want to find the complexity of a search, that's a little bigger question. A search on a balanced binary tree has complexity of O(log<sub>2</sub>(n)). A search on a balanced ternary tree would be O(log<sub>3</sub>(n)). At worst, a search on an unbalanced tree would have to travel through every node, so the complexity is O(n).